# R: tailoring legend in ggplot boxplot leaves two separate legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, boxplot

I have created a faceted boxplot using the ggplot2 package. The R code is as follows:

```
version.labs <- c(`1`="Version 1.0", `2`="Version 2.0", `3`="Version 3.0", `4`="Version 4.0", `5`="Version 5.0")
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Subsystem), y=Risk.value, fill=factor(Version)) ) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.3, height=0.2), aes(colour=factor(Version)), alpha=0.9) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE) + facet_grid(.~Version, labeller = as_labeller(version.labs)) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=9, color="black", face="bold"))
```

The resulting plot looks pretty good (as shown below) exept for the legend.

[image]

In the legend I want to change the title as well as the text label for each item. The title should be "Version" and the labels "Version 1.0", ..., "Version 5.0".

I've tried various ways but they all add a new separate legend. The new legend looks good, but the old one is still there which doesn't look good and I can't find a way to remove it.

The last thing I tried was to add the scale_color_manual() function, like this:

```
scale_color_manual(name = "Version", labels=c("v1.0","v2.0","v3.0","v4.0","v5.0"), values=c("grey","blue","green","red","black"))
```

This results in a boxplot that looks like this.

[image]

As can be seen there are two legends. So, close but no cigar. Any hints on how to solve this are appreciated.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. But I think you'll need _both_ a `scale_color_manual` and a `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that as well and it didn't solve the problem. However, I solved it using another solution as is explained in seperate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was that I had placed my aestetic fill function `aes()` in the general `ggplot()`. This should instead be placed in `geom_boxplot()`, otherwise both the general `ggplot()` as well as the `geom_boxplot()` will add a legend. So I fixed that, and then I used `guides()` to update the title in the `geom_boxplot()` legend. The full code looks as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Subsystem), y=Risk.value) ) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.3, height=0.2), aes(colour=factor(Version)), alpha=0.9) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE, aes(fill=factor(Version))) + facet_grid(.~Version, labeller = as_labeller(version.labs)) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=9, color="black", face="bold")) +
  labs(x="Risk distribution per software version and subsystem type", y="Normalized risk value") + 
  guides(color=guide_legend("Version"))
```

The final plot looks like this, which I'm happy with.

[image: Final plot]

Answer (score -1):

You are using `fill` argument for grouping and generation of legend. may be instead of `scale_color_manual` you can use `scale_fill_manual` to override the existing legend

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with the following command: `scale_fill_manual(name = "Version", labels=c("v1.0","v2.0","v3.0","v4.0","v5.0"), values=c("grey", "blue", "green", "red", "black"))` But the result is close to identical to the second boxplot, i.e. two legends :-/